# Delete putty "Default Settings" modification to original

Tags: putty

I'm using putty to access linux bash. I have overwritten the "Default Settings" with some modification. 
How can I set the defaults back to the original?

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution with regedit.

All sessions are in the registry under:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions
```

There I delete the session "default%20settings".

Comment: I agree. Funnily enough, the "Default Settings" Session cannot be deleted in the PuTTY GUI Dialogue. You have to use RegEdit or RegEdit32. All other Sessions can be deleted interactively by using the "Delete" Button in PuTTY.

Answer (score 8):

Locate where putty.exe is installed. Open command prompt. Type putty.exe -cleanup
Thats it

Comment: According to the PuTTY documentation -cleanup deletes MUCH more than just the "Default Settings" Profile!